# AsyncRead for UdpSocket

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-async-std

I'm trying to implement AsyncRead for a UdpSocket that have an async recv function and I have some difficulties calling poll on my future:

```
use async_std::{
    io::Read as AsyncRead,
    net::UdpSocket,
};

struct MyUdpWrapper {
    socket: Arc<UdpSocket>,
    fut: Option<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<usize>>>>,
}

impl AsyncRead for MyUdpWrapper {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    fn poll_read(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Poll<Result<usize>> {
        let this = Pin::into_inner(self);
        let fut = this.fut.unwrap_or(Box::new(this.socket.recv(buf)));
        let fut = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut *fut) };
        fut.poll(cx)
    }
}
```

I was thinking storing the future in an option so it continues to live after the 1st poll but I'm not clear about how to do that exactly.
The async [recv()](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.recv) returns a Result so I guess I should store an `Option<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<size>>>>` but that seems a bit cumbersome?

Is there a good way to call an async function in `poll_read` (or `poll_*` in general)?

Comment: Why did you edit the error message out of the question?

Comment: because the error message wasn't really my question and I didn't want it to be the focus of an answer. Basically I added a Box<dyn ...> and no more error message but it still feels wrong

Answer (score 2):

Your code is actually unsound since `UdpSocket::recv()` borrows the provided buffer, so you can't release the buffer until the future is dropped, but the buffer given to `poll_read()` is only temporary. I also think you want something more like `this.fut.get_or_insert_with()` instead of `this.fut.unwrap_or()`.

Under the hood, `async_std::net::UdpSocket::recv()` actually uses `async_io::Async::<std::net::UdpSocket>::recv()`, which calls the `read_with()` method.

We need to use `async_io::Async<std::net::UdpSocket>` directly. `Async<T>` [already implements `AsyncRead` when `T: Read`](https://docs.rs/async-io/1.12.0/src/async_io/lib.rs.html#1075-1103). This is not the case for `UdpSocket`, but we can write a similar implementation:

```rust
use std::{
    future::Future,
    net::UdpSocket,
    pin::Pin,
    sync::Arc,
    task::{Context, Poll},
};

use async_io::Async;
use async_std::{io::Read as AsyncRead, io::Result};

struct MyUdpWrapper {
    socket: Arc<Async<UdpSocket>>,
}

impl AsyncRead for MyUdpWrapper {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut [u8],
    ) -> Poll<Result<usize>> {
        loop {
            match self.socket.get_ref().recv(buf) {
                // Calls std::net::UdpSocket::recv()
                Err(err) if err.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {}
                res => return Poll::Ready(res),
            }
            match Pin::new(&mut self.socket.readable()).poll(cx) {
                Poll::Ready(res) => res?,
                Poll::Pending => return Poll::Pending,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: it's a bit unclear to me why `async_io::Async::poll_read()` uses `poll_readable()` but `async_std::net::UdpSocket::recv()` uses `readable()`; it seems that only the latter registers the current task for wakeup, so that's what I chose here).